# How to bulk move existing content of mysql date column to new one of different type?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, date, sql-update

i would like to transfer the content of my current MYSQL Table´s date field of format (YYMMDD) e.g. 20170411 to a new existing one as UNIX TIMESTAMPS (1491920214).

Is this possible as one query statement and how would it looks like? Or do i have to convert all data of my existing column first?

- Table = wp_postmeta
- Old Date Field = old_meta_date
- New Date Field = new_meta_date

Thanks for your kind help in advance.

Comment: What is the datatype of the original column? What have you tried? Show your code that isn't working.

Comment: Not tried anything yet as i don't know where to start. Currently inspecting the tables columns at phpMyAdmin.

Comment: which datatype is the column old_meta_date???

Comment: The current column is of type longtext. I tried to update one of it by selecting new type of unix timestamp and compared the output to http://www.unixtimestamp.com. Where results are different. From the Website it says 20170323 = 1490227200, MySQL = 1490223600.

Comment: Sorry current is varchar(255)

Answer (score 0):

looking to you sample seem that your original column could be a varchar

if so you can use

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(concat(substr(old_meta_date,1,2),'-', 
            substr(old_meta_date,3,2) , '-',
            substr(old_meta_date,5,2) ))
from wp_postmeta;
```

so for update  you can

```
update wp_postmeta
set new_meta_date =  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(concat(substr(old_meta_date,1,2),'-', 
                    substr(old_meta_date,3,2) , '-',
                    substr(old_meta_date,5,2) ));
```

or  using a cast to date

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST(old_meta_date AS DATE))
from wp_postmeta;

update wp_postmeta
set new_meta_date =  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CAST(old_meta_date AS DATE));
```

Comment: Will making a backup of the current table and try this out, thanks. Will let you know.